# What is the best approach to building a custom video player web browser plugin?

Tags: java, html, plugins, synchronization, video-streaming

I need to stream multiple videos in a web browser and have them all be synchronized; I also need to be able to switch between audio channels on the fly.  Despite a lot of research, it looks as though at present this is impossible using the current browser implementations of HTML5 video.  Flash seems to have the same problem.  There are forums full of people wanting to do on-the-fly, in-band audio and video switching with sync, and multi-video playback with sync, but no real way to do it.

It's in the HTML5 spec for the future, actually, but has no browser implementation yet.

So, I need to build a custom plugin or application.

What is the best approach to doing this?  Would something like Google Web Toolkit be a good place to start?  Is client-side Java a good approach to building something this custom but with ease of deployability (vs say OS-specific C++ plugins, for example)?

Comment: Trying to think a bit out-of-the-box, you could composite all of your video into one source on your server, and then create multiple video elements on your HTML5 page-- for each video element, you could map it to display only the smaller, initial video channel.  I've never worked with Video in HTML5, but I could try to put some code together for you later this evening if that sounds like a possibility.

Comment: @RLH: sounds pretty interesting.  So you're saying have all of the videos in squares one big file, but change the viewport of multiple elements to match each square?  Seems very interesting indeed...  Is this possible?  Reminds me of the now-popular concept of having multiple page element images in a single file, and modulating the background position to show them depending upon e.g. a mouseover, etc.

Comment: "Reminds me of the now-popular concept of having multiple page element images in a single file" Yes, that's exactly what I meant.  I wouldn't know how to composite the video, but on the HTML5 side, you certainly can display portions of a playing video on a canvas object.  Additionally, you can scale, rotate, skew, etc the sections of the video on-the-fly in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaFX 2(An official supported Java library) has a video player which I've seen modified interesting in a 3d world and basically doing what you want. Currently it only supports flv, but they probably change it like it was in JavaFX 1 and support what ever installed codecs on ones computer, once out of beta.

Edit: Checking over the video stuff again not totally sure on keeping things in sync when this is on there roadmap (http://javafx.com/roadmap/)

> Synchronized Media and Animations
>
> Sometimes applications need to have very tightly aligned media and
>   animation in a timeline. JavaFX 2.0 will provide support to tie a
>   timeline to a specific media stream such that events in the timeline
>   occur in sync with events in the media stream.